# ListenAndServe returns net.DNSError "nodename nor servname provided"

Tags: http, docker, go

I am trying to write a go http server but I have an issue when I try to listen to incoming connections. 
HW setup: MacOS Sierra 10.12.4, docker 17.03

I have a yml file that will open a . phpmyadmin and sql:

```
mysql:
  extends:
    service: mysql-5.7
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
  links:
  - "mysql:db"
  ports:
  - "8080:80"
```

This seems to work fine.
After this I wrote a go file to connect and listen to connections:

```
stack := negroni.New()
stack.Use(cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
    AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"},
    AllowedHeaders:   []string{"*"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
}))

external := &http.Server{
    Addr:    "10001",
    Handler: stack,
}

// Start the server, listening for incomming connections.
go func() {
    err = external.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        level.Error(logger).Log("msg", "error while listening", "err", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}()
```

This will generate the error:

> level=error time=2017-06-19T09:28:14.726843314Z app=“Falbala” env=local pid=1084 host=P5RO-PORT367.local msg="error while listening" err="listen tcp: lookup tcp/10001”: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go), address value should be a string.

```
// ListenAndServe always returns a non-nil error.
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error {
    server := &Server{Addr: addr, Handler: handler}
    return server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

Can you try?

```
external := http.Server{
    Addr:    ":10001",
    Handler: stack,
}
```